# WKWebView only showing desktop site

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I just migrated from UIWebView and my new WKWebView will only show the desktop version of the site I'm loading. My UIWebView showed the responsive site appropriately.

I have tried forcing a mobile User-Agent and confirmed that it is coming in on to the server

```
let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11A465 Twitter for iPhone"
webView.customUserAgent = userAgent
```

Does anyone have any other ideas I can try? Thanks

Comment: What site are you loading and how does it detect mobile/non-mobile? Maybe it's a way to go from the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have control over the CSS of the page I'm displaying.

It was using the following to calculate breakpoints:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1

@media screen and (min-width: 650px)
```

Adding this to the template that uses that CSS solved it for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width={{ $width }}, shrink-to-fit=YES">
```

Where `{{ $width }}` is:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
```

Comment: @RyanPoolos odd, it's still working for me in our app. What is yours doing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but from what I can tell its ignoring `@media screen and (min-width: 480px)` and just rendering the desktop version zoomed in and cropped. I have lots of other sites working as expected, but this seems to be the only one with @media and the only one failing. So suspect its related but until its fixed I can't confirm haha

Comment: @RyanPoolos can you share a link? Does it work if you open it in mobile safari?

Comment: If I save it to an html file and open it in Mac Safari Mobile Test Mode it works. Its an email not a website so its not easy to just open it directly. It works in the iOS Mail client. But in a WKWebView it has issues.